# var request: Alamofire.Request? Use of undeclared type Alamofire

Tags: ios, xcode, swift3, alamofire

I'm converting my swift 2.2 code to swift3 code in Xcode 8 and I have this line:

```
var request: Alamofire.Request?
```

which is producing this error:

```
Use of undeclared type Alamofire.
```

How can I fix this error? I have read the migration guide but I don't see anything which helps me. I am using Alamofire 4.0.1

Comment: Have you done `import Alamofire`?

Comment: I added @import Alamofire to the top of the file buut no difference. I'm not sure that's the correct location for it.

Comment: That's the correct place, but `@` shouldn't be there. Also make sure you've run `pod install` command from terminal and opened generated workspace, not project itself

Comment: Thanks, I added import Alamofire to the top of the file and saved it then ran Build again and the problem did not reappear. I do have @import Alamofire in my bridging header file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code itself is ok. The issue is most probably with importing `Alamofire` module

Try the following steps:

1. `import Alamofire` in the swift file where you need to use Alamofire module (and `@import Alamofire` in bridging header if needed)
2. Clean (Cmd + Shift + K)
3. Build the project

If you see `No such module` error, you should run `pod install` command from Terminal and open the generated workspace instead of the project itself.

Comment: I had @import Alamofire in the bridging header but still needed to import Alamofire in my file.